# Internet Explorer 9 addon development help

Tags: internet-explorer-9, toolbar, browser-addons

So I'm trying to write a toolbar for internet explorer 9, and I can't really find a good place to get started. I have a couple questions...

1) are IE9 toolbars written with C#, C++?, or Visual C++? I know that .NET isn't a good bet for writing a toolbar, (And i'm tempted to go with visual C++ because it's microsoft's baby), but I've seen people write that C++, C#, and Visual C++ can all be used, and I've seen people say that only one of those three can be used.

2) Are there any good books about this subject? I've been looking through amazon, barnes and noble, and google books, and can't find a book specifically about writing addons for IE9. (I've found a few tutorials, but for the most part, they leave quite a bit to be desired)

3) I have some experience writing addons for firefox, but I can't find any comparisons between writing addons for firefox and IE9 on the web. Can anyone tell me if my experience with firefox will in any way be relevant to writing a toolbar in IE9?

4) I was told to use windows template library by a friend, he said it would help with designing IE9 toolbars. Another friend then told me that the WTL is completely useless to develop toolbars for IE9. Were either of them correct?

Thank you for your help.